# How to map something like this

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I've never seen something like this before

```
EntityA
@Id
long id

@Column(name ="field1")
String field1
@Column(name ="field2")
String field2

@IdClass(compositePK.class)
EntityB
@Id
String field1
@Id
String field2

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
EntityA myEntityA
```

Ok all is ok the `tableB` need to have the `EntityA` as foreign key but defined on the id not on `field1,field2`.

I get error like

> Foreign key (FK74D979395D87E41E:EntityA [id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (EntityA [field1,field2])

I understand that hibernate required that the FK need to be the same as the PK but I can't made this the `entityB` PK must stay `field1,field2` I can't change `EntityA` for the moment.

Comment: That code is unreadable.  Reformat it so we can read and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what I understand from your code, you've got `EntityA` with simple PK `id` and `EntityB` with a composite PK `CompositePK`. For a `@OneToOne` association to work, both entities need to share a primary key/have the same PK class (or at least a unique constraint simulating the PK)

It is not possible to use this kind of mapping with this structure, you should either:

- Adapt your data model consistently, so that both `EntityA` and `EntityB` share their PK, or there's a FK from `EntityB` to `EntityA`.
- Use a `OneToMany` instead, even if it will always contain 'one' in the 'many' side.

See this section on Hibernate Reference for some background: [2.2.5. Mapping entity associations/relationships - One to one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1382), specially the second part talking about FK's:

> There are three cases for one-to-one associations: either the
>   associated entities share the same primary keys values, a foreign key
>   is held by one of the entities (note that this FK column in the
>   database should be constrained unique to simulate one-to-one
>   multiplicity), or a association table is used to store the link
>   between the 2 entities (a unique constraint has to be defined on each
>   fk to ensure the one to one multiplicity).